# How to get SASL authentication to work with DIGEST-MD5 for OpenLDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap, sasl, saslauthd

I'm setting up OpenLDAP `slapd` on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr. I want certain instances (replication etc.) that aren't users to be able to login via `SASL` using `DIGEST-MD5` mechanism.

Unlike users, they are **not** supposed to have a corresponding DN (along with the password) in the directory tree. Instead, their credentials are supposed to be stored externally, hence `SASL`.

I'm using `saslauthd` right now (this is not a hard requirement if it can be made to work with direct access to the sasldb, for instance) and it works fine using mechanisms `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` while it fails using mechanisms `DIGEST-MD5` and `CRAM-MD5`.

*What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I get it to work with `DIGEST-MD5`?*

OpenLDAP is configured for `SASL` in `/etc/ldap/sasl2/slapd.conf` like this:

```
mech_list: EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
saslauthd_path: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
```

The interesting (changed) options in `/etc/default/saslauthd` are:

```
START=yes
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
```

They result in `saslauthd` being started like so:

```
/usr/sbin/saslauthd -a sasldb -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5
```

I reproduce the failing case with `DIGEST-MD5` like this:

```
# ldapsearch -U replication -ZZ -Y DIGEST-MD5 -H ldap://ldap-master.example.com/ -b "dc=example,dc=com" "(objectClass=*)"
SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
Please enter your password: 
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database
```

The part in the slapd log where it seems to fail (logging is on `any`) looks like this:

```
slapd[23330]: [rw] authid: "uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth" -> "uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth"
slapd[23330]: slap_parseURI: parsing uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth
slapd[23330]: >>> dnNormalize: <uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth>
slapd[23330]: <<< dnNormalize: <uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth>
slapd[23330]: <==slap_sasl2dn: Converted SASL name to uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth
slapd[23330]: slap_sasl_getdn: dn:id converted to uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth
slapd[23330]: SASL Canonicalize [conn=1002]: slapAuthcDN="uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth"
slapd[23330]: SASL [conn=1002] Failure: no secret in database
slapd[23330]: SASL [conn=1002] Debug: DIGEST-MD5 common mech dispose
slapd[23330]: send_ldap_result: conn=1002 op=2 p=3
slapd[23330]: send_ldap_result: err=49 matched="" text="SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database"
slapd[23330]: send_ldap_response: msgid=3 tag=97 err=49
```

There's nothing in `/var/log/auth.log` nor in the debug output of `saslauthd` when I run it manually, which likely indicates that `slapd` didn't even get as far as handing off the authentication to `saslauthd` (in contrast with the working case, see below).

I reproduce the working case with `PLAIN` or `LOGIN` like this:

```
# ldapsearch -U replication -ZZ -Y PLAIN -H ldap://ldap-master.example.com/ -b "dc=example,dc=com" "(objectClass=*)"
SASL/PLAIN authentication started
Please enter your password: 
SASL username: replication
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
…
```

The corresponding part in the `slapd` log that indicated failure for the case above now looks like this:

```
slapd[23330]: [rw] authid: "uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth" -> "uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth"
slapd[23330]: slap_parseURI: parsing uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth
slapd[23330]: >>> dnNormalize: <uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth>
slapd[23330]: <<< dnNormalize: <uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth>
slapd[23330]: <==slap_sasl2dn: Converted SASL name to uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth
slapd[23330]: slap_sasl_getdn: dn:id converted to uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth
slapd[23330]: SASL Canonicalize [conn=1006]: slapAuthcDN="uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth"
slapd[23330]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
slapd[23330]: daemon: activity on:
slapd[23330]: 
slapd[23330]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
slapd[23330]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
slapd[23330]: daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
slapd[23330]: SASL proxy authorize [conn=1006]: authcid="replication" authzid="replication"
slapd[23330]: conn=1006 op=1 BIND authcid="replication" authzid="replication"
slapd[23330]: SASL Authorize [conn=1006]:  proxy authorization allowed authzDN=""
slapd[23330]: send_ldap_sasl: err=0 len=-1
slapd[23330]: conn=1006 op=1 BIND dn="uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth" mech=PLAIN sasl_ssf=0 ssf=128
slapd[23330]: do_bind: SASL/PLAIN bind: dn="uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth" sasl_ssf=0
slapd[23330]: send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=97 err=0
```

Both `/var/log/auth.log` and the debug output from `saslauthd` now contain this:

```
saslauthd[23354]: rel_accept_lock : released accept lock
saslauthd[23358]: get_accept_lock : acquired accept lock
saslauthd[23354]: cache_get_rlock : attempting a read lock on slot: 458
saslauthd[23354]: cache_lookup    : [login=replication] [service=] [realm=ldap]: not found, update pending
saslauthd[23354]: cache_un_lock   : attempting to release lock on slot: 458
saslauthd[23354]: cache_get_wlock : attempting a write lock on slot: 458
saslauthd[23354]: cache_commit    : lookup committed
saslauthd[23354]: cache_un_lock   : attempting to release lock on slot: 458
saslauthd[23354]: do_auth         : auth success: [user=replication] [service=ldap] [realm=] [mech=sasldb]
saslauthd[23354]: do_request      : response: OK
```

Apparently, there must be some difference in how it works with `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` vs. `DIGEST-MD5` and `CRAM-MD5`.

Update and clarification:

The DNs used for authorizing access to the tree are `uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth` and `uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth` respectively and according to section 15.2.5 of http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html those DNs don't need to actually exist in the tree (which must be true at least for `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` as it is working fine there).
For testing purposes I'm currently using `olcAccess: to * by dn.regex="replication" read by * break` to ensure the replication login gets at least read access to everything (yes, I know that's not secure and I will give it proper permissions for production) in the master LDAP tree.

The credentials are in `/etc/sasldb2` and they are successfully checked against when using `PLAIN` or `LOGIN` (see above). For reference, it looks like that:

```
# sasldblistusers2
replication@ldap-master: userPassword
…

# db_dump -p /etc/sasldb2 
VERSION=3
format=print
type=hash
h_nelem=4
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
 replication\00ldap-master\00userPassword
 PasswordCensored
…
```

However, in the case of `DIGEST-MD5` and `CRAM-MD5` it doesn't seem to contact `saslauthd` at all (due to me missing something or doing something wrong, possibly), so the database is likely not consulted, either.

Comment: How does ldap know what access controls the connection is allowed if it doesn't have an associated DN? You also didn't show if you added the shared secret to sasldb.

Comment: The access to the tree is a higher level problem that's not relevant here. It does get assigned a DN when doing an SASL login (`uid=replication,cn=digest-md5,cn=auth` and `uid=replication,cn=plain,cn=auth` as can be seen in the log outputs above) and according to the Note in section 15.2.5 of http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html the DN doesn't need to exist in the tree. And the working `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` mechanisms suggest that this is true. Also, the working `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` cases show that the credentials are correctly taken from the sasldb. I will clarify that in my question.

Comment: Does DNS have reverse pointer records for the target servers?

Comment: Yes, all our nodes have PTR records (and address -> domain -> address resolves to the same address, if it matters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recipe is for OpenLDAP to check directly `/etc/sasldb2`.

First step: ensure the `/etc/sasldb2` is owned by slapd user.

Next step: have `slapd` not to look for credentials in directory tree, which is done as following:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSaslAuxprops
olcSaslAuxprops: sasldb
```

Later, you will also need a `olcAuthzRegexp` rule, but in order to test if auth works, it is not necessary.

These settings are working on Debian GNU/Linux Jessie OpenLDAP-2.4.40 builded from source.

Comment: Originally I tried with and without `sasldb` in `olcSaslAuxprops` and it didn't make a difference for me. I did some extensive tests and it turns out that setting `olcSaslAuxprops` is one puzzle piece of a working configuration, so I'm accepting your solution.

Answer (score 3):

The CRAM-MD5 and DIGEST-MD5 methods are impossible with "pwcheck_method: saslauthd". They needs plain, unencrypted passwords in a LDAP directory itself.

Comment: Why? Alternatively, what about `pwcheck_method: auxprop` and having slapd thus access the sasldb directly? This should be possible, right? The passwords in the sasldb are plaintext. If possible, how do I configure that?

Comment: I can only point to http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201511/msg00142.html if you want to try "auxprop". I never tried it myself.

Comment: It turns out that setting `pwcheck_method` to one value or another doesn't make a difference at all for mechanisms `DIGEST-MD5` and `CRAM-MD5` (however, it does for `PLAIN` and `LOGIN`). Thus your answer doesn't apply to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some extensive tests against various configurations with different credentials in the `sasldb`.

In conclusion it turns out the problem that most haunted me here was that, according to which authentication method (`saslauthd` vs. `auxprop`) is used (which in turn is dependent on the requested authentication mechanism - `DIGEST-MD5`/`CRAM-MD5` vs. `PLAIN`/`LOGIN`), it was looking for a different `domain`. I did not expect that and as I had only one user-domain-pair in the `sasldb`, it didn't find the other one.

I'll list some of my conclusions and observations in hope that it will help others understand the problem and work around it:

1. In case you request `PLAIN` or `LOGIN` mechanism, `slapd` will use the authentication method configured under `pwcheck_method` in `/etc/ldap/sasl2/slapd.conf`.
2. In case you request `DIGEST-MD5` or `CRAM-MD5` mechanism, `slapd` will always use the `auxprop` method, regardless of what is configured for `pwcheck_method`.
3. In effect, it means you can have `slapd` use the same method for all 4 mechanisms if you configure `pwcheck_method: auxprop`. Or you can decide to use 2 different methods if you configure something else for `pwcheck_method`.
4. In any case, `auxprop_plugin` in `/etc/ldap/sasl2/slapd.conf` is ignored. Instead `slapd` uses what is configured for `olcSaslAuxprops` in its own configuration database. Note that this is true both for the implicit `auxprop` method when requesting `DIGEST-MD5` or `CRAM-MD5` mechanisms as well as for the explicitly configured `pwcheck_method: auxprop` when requesting one of the other 2 mechanisms.
5. In my case, `saslauthd` looks up the credentials with the unadorned hostname (i. e. just `ldap-master`) as the `domain` component. If I were to take an educated guess, I'd say it uses something like `gethostname()` to come up with that, so this might be configurable somehow.
6. In my case, when going through `auxprop` one way or the other, `slapd` uses the fully qualified domain name (i. e. `ldap-master.example.com`) as the `domain` component. It likely gets that from the original request URL (my alternatives for generating the request are limited when I want to use STARTTLS and want to be able to correctly verify the server certificate, which asks for a matching domain name), but it can likely be configured by setting `olcSaslHost` in `slapd`'s configuration database. Note that I haven't tried configuring it.

So for coming up with a working configuration, you have several options:

1. If you're fine with just `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` mechanisms over STARTTLS, configure `pwcheck_method` in `/etc/ldap/sasl2/slapd.conf` as required. If it's going to be `auxprop`, also configure `olcSaslAuxprops` in `slapd`'s configuration database (set it to `sasldb`, for instance, if you want to use `/etc/sasldb2` as credential store).
2. If you're fine with just `DIGEST-MD5` (I usually see `CRAM-MD5` recommended against due to inferior security, so try avoiding it), set `olcSaslAuxprops` in `slapd`'s configuration database, as the `auxprop` method is going to be used, no matter what you configure for `pwcheck_method`.
3. If you want to be able to use mechanisms from both the set `DIGEST-MD5`, `CRAM-MD5` (however, try to avoid `CRAM-MD5`) as well as the set `PLAIN`, `LOGIN` (make sure those are only used over an encrypted connection, like a STARTTLS-one) and prefer to use the same authentication method for all of them as well as check against the same set of credentials, you're limited to `auxprop`. Configure `pwcheck_method: auxprop` in `/etc/ldap/sasl2/slapd.conf` and set `olcSaslAuxprops` in `slapd`'s configuration database as required.
4. If you want to be able to use mechanisms from both sets while using different authentication methods for them (sounds like an administration nightmare to me, but there you go), configure `pwcheck_method` in `/etc/ldap/sasl2/slapd.conf` accordingly for `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` and remember that you're forced to use `auxprop` for `DIGEST-MD5` (and `CRAM-MD5` if you insist) and set `olcSaslAuxprops` in `slapd`'s configuration database as required.

   - If you happen to configure `saslauthd` for unhashed mechanisms and make sure that saslauthd accesses a different database than what `slapd` accesses through `auxprop` or use something else than `sasldb` for `olcSaslAuxprops`, you have them nicely separated and nothing to worry about.
   - If you happen to configure `saslauthd` for unhashed mechanisms and `sasldb` for `auxprop` for the hashed mechanisms and have them access the same credentials database, you have 3 options, in order of preference:

     1. Somehow, make sure that both `saslauthd` as well as `slapd` accessing the sasldb directly through `auxprop` query the credentials with the same `domain` (try setting `olcSaslHost` or coercing `saslauthd` to use a FQDN), so you will only have to care about one credential entry per entity to authenticate.
     2. Deliberately make the decision to use different credentials for the unhashed vs. the hashed mechanisms. Use a `userid`-`hostname` pair for the unhashed mechanisms over `saslauthd` and use a `userid`-`hostname.domain.name` pair for the hashed mechanisms via `auxprop`.
     3. Keep two credential entries per entity to authenticate - one with 'hostname' and the other with 'hostname.domain.name' - and keep the passwords of both in sync (ugh).